# InvientCharts Vaadin not working

Tags: vaadin

I am working with Vaadin 6 and want to use InvientCharts because it is free. 
After compiling the widgetset, all vaadins component instead of invientCharts are working. The error which appears as text on my app is the following:

[image]

After trying everything, including setting up a complete new project, I followed this tutorial: http://www.nightswatch.de/?x=entry:entry120125-234412

But it is still not working and shows the same error.
Has anyone an idea what is going on here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

When you receive the message that the widgetset does not contain implementation of XY,
then usually you have forgotten to compile it with the additional jar files or you did not specify the new widgetset.

The nightswatch example is incomplete, you need to compile the widgetset.

Simplest would be to use the maven build script to build all dependencies and compile stuff as needed (or use eclipse for this)